# Returning formula in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheet in want to subtract one cell with another based on a value in yet another cell.

example:

```
If cell A1 = "Yes" 
  subtract B1 from C1 

If cell A1 = "No"
  subtract B1 from D1

If cell A1 = ""
  subtract B1 from C1
```

I think a have to build a little script for this one (not sure) and have come up with this:

```
function sub() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var nRange = ss.getRangeByName("sub");
  var group = nRange.getValues();;

  var range;

    if ( group == "Yes" ) {
     range = '=Q15-N15' }
    else if ( group == "No" ) {
     range = "=Q15-M15"}
    else if ( group == "" ) {
     range = "=Q15-M15"}

    return range
    }
```

Now it returns the proper range, but the formula is not going in effect. The script pastes the range literally in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.getValues()` to read the content of a range, you will receive a two-dimensional array of values - even if there is only one cell in the range. If you really want just one value, use `.getValue()` instead.

Because you're getting an array, all three of your `if` tests evaluate to `false`, and none set a value for `range`. Try giving `range` a default value to start:

```
var range = 'Range not set';
```

Note: [Custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions) return **Values**, they cannot set a cell's formula. Your function could return the result of a calculation, or a line of text to display in a cell. If you must set a formula, you'll have to do so using a function that's invoked some other way, and use [`Range.setFormula()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#setFormula%28String%29).